# Interfacing Current transformer with PIC16f88

Tags: current-transformer

I am trying to interface Current transformer with PIC16F88. I have used 120 Ohms burden( recommended is 125 ohms in datasheet) ,I am using 20:1 A CT with winding ratio 1:2500. The link to datasheet is :http://www.shahelectronics.net/MediaImages/SET2106-2500-20A-20AMP_CT.pdf   So please help me with some techniques for interfacing and coding.

Comment: The output of a current transformer will be AC, so you may want to rectify and filter it before applying it to the PIC if you are only interested in the RMS value, rather than the actual AC waveform.

Comment: yes I am interested in RMS value. So how should I interface it with PIC?

Answer (score 1):

> I am using 20:1 A CT with winding ratio 1:2500.

Not quite. You are using a 2500:1 transformer and this transforms a current of 1 amp in the primary to a current of 0.4mA in the secondary (providing you have an appropriate load).

> I am interested in RMS value

If you are measuring load current of some AC appliance then the current is likely not to be very sinusoidal and the only realistic way of determining true RMS is to sample the output waveform at many times the AC power frequency.

The CT's output can be offset and biased so that the full waveform (at max current) is within the upper and lower bounds of your PIC's ADC. You then sample this at (say) 1kHz, square each sample, accumulate over a period (say 1 second) and then take the square root of the accumulated 1 second value.

If you don't want to go to that trouble, you can usually place a diode in series with the burden resistor to get a rectified half wave output (also add a clamping diode for the negative half cycle of the CT's output). You can also use a bridge rectifier between burden and CT but because there are two diode drops you need to check the data sheet to see if the extra volt-drop from two diodes will cause inaccuracies. This can of course be easily filtered into a relatively smooth DC value before feeding into your PIC's ADC input. It won't be exactly true-RMS but may be good enough for your needs.

Comment: *"place a diode in series with the burden resistor"* -- are you sure that's what you meant? That sounds dangerous to me, because it would leave the CT unburdened for half of each cycle. Perhaps you should include a diagram that shows exactly what you mean.

Comment: @DaveTweed I forgot to mention that a clamping diode is also required - fixing....

Comment: Still sounds risky to me. You really want the burden resistor connected directly to the CT. If a rectified output is needed, a simple opamp-based precision rectifier is normally used.

Comment: @Andyaka I have tried using this method but I was unsuccessful, and I have also heard about the diode voltage drops restrict accuracy. Is their any other way?

Comment: @DaveTweed The Opamp based precision rectifier is good but its  complex I have seen this circuit from CR magnetics:https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.crmagnetics.com%2FProducts%2FAssets%2FProductPDFs%2FPrecision%2520Rectifier%2520Circuit%2520for%2520CT%2520Signal%2520Conditioning.pdf&ei=yPTVVKf8MMOjugSfnIDwDw&usg=AFQjCNGaUR791aWErgaybamIjYvB7fEGFQ&sig2=7tt_Z3WF1uYbwmv_n-lxyw

Comment: @MrunalAhirrao: That isn't a particularly good design. There are better precision full-wave rectifier circuits that don't force the opamp output to saturate, which kills its transient response. Look for ones that don't have a diode in series with the opamp output terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the voltage across the output of the CT should be as close to zero as possible.  That said . . .

The standard circuit for rectifying the output of a current transformer is to use a bridge rectifier connected to the output of the CT, then place your burden resistor across the output of the bridge rectifier.

The reason you do this is because the CT acts like a current source.  Because of this, the output voltage from the CT rises to compensate for the voltage drop caused by the rectifier diodes.

This isn't perfect but the error introduced by this is very small.